# The horrible wordsearch: Can you decypher the word-search puzzle to find the final clue?

Tags: cipher, word-search

This will be a tricky one, I think.
The whole puzzle is self-contained in the information between the two horizontal bars below.

The answer to this riddle is a book title of 5 words. The book is rather well known literature and can be legally obtained for free as e-book.

The word search-puzzle comes with a few *important* clues (see below), but there is no additional information to this puzzle outside the two horizontal bars.

**Can you find the 5-word-title ?**

The whole puzzle and the book title are in English. Although there are several "stages" to this puzzle, you will need to look at the puzzle as a whole, i.e. the additional clues may not be disregarded. (Or you will not solve this puzzle.)

---

> Words are born as letters, but they reach adulthood when they are six. (*And this puzzle is not child's play!*)
>
> You find us from East to West and West to East, from North to South and South to North. And in between, can we also be seen.  We do not jump, we do not bend, a straight line we form, from start to end.

```
C E O F K O S D B R P 
Y L T O I W G U M S R 
J E S P B O U A A K W 
W I L U W S D G J T E 
A N E A Q L H K G Y N 
D N A S Y S C Y L P L 
Z O K L O E D T L W Z 
N U G S Y C O F A R T 
F E H U F D S T L E S 
J U P H Z V H R T Y U 
W V C X V Y E Y C A D
```

> We meet at Waterloo station.

```
__ <-> __
__ <-> __
__ <-> __
__ <-> __
__ <-> __
__ <-> __

B*H***
B***KF***
H****H-*UG
**F**QU***
M*****G*
*********
P**K**
******
U*U****
V******
```

---

Comment: I found "FART," but I'm not sure that's in the answer.  Did Dickens ever write a book of poo jokes?

Comment: Liking it very much! "It was the best of wordsearches, it was the worst of wordsearches".

Comment: Words are all straight, right? No boggle-type any-adjacent-letter thing? And all in a row, no every-other, every-third, etc?

Comment: Hmm, a 5-word title without "the"? Are all the words in the title supposed to appear in the word search?

Comment: @Kevin, I'm interested, why are you thinking that the title doesn't contain 'the'? You might well be right, I just hadn't spotted that myself.

Comment: Also I'd like to point out that Charles Dickens wrote "A Tale of Two Cities" while staying in the ***Waterloo*** Hotel.

Comment: @AE I was thinking all words came from the word search, which doesn't contain "the", see my follow up question.

Comment: @Kevin, ah, I see. Given the 'cryptogram' tag I've been assuming that something more complicated was going on. ;) Checked wordsearch for all 25 variations of Caeser cipher, nothing jumped out at me. Is there a Waterloo-related cipher? Or maybe try 'Waterloo' as a keyword for something like vigenere? A cipher used at the battle of Waterloo maybe?

Comment: I found the words "THE", "OF", "A", "AN", "ATE", "GUM", "DOG", "FAR", "FART", "FALL", "FAT", "MASK", "ANNA", "ANNE", "TALE", "TALES", "DUG", "TO", "TOP" "RYE", and "BSOD". And probably there are plenty others.

Comment: Time to write up a program to scan for words in the dictionary... Nah too much work, manual probably be easier XD

Comment: @Victor - If you want to include "A", you should include "I" too! And what's "BSOD" doing there??

Comment: Blue Screen Of Death

Comment: @Victor where do you see "TALES" or "THE"?

Comment: yay:) I'm thinking maybe the six 'a to b' symbols mean a six-position shift.

Comment: @Kevin, the T at line 9, second H at line 10, E at line 11; The same T at line 9, the A at line 8, L, E and S in line 9 following the T.

Comment: @Victor that's not straight lines, which I'd expect in a word search.

Comment: @Kevin I would not assume such thing. Those puzzles are so crazy that anything except the obvious could be possible.

Comment: Is it "The Hound of the Baskervilles"? I want to check before posting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have part of the puzzle:

The Arrows:

> A <--> O
>  D <--> R
>  E <--> S
>  C <--> T
>  N <--> L
>  I <--> Y

The Words:

> Behind
> Breakfast
> Hearth-Rug
> Infrequent
> Mornings
> Occasions
> Picked
> Seated
> Usually
> Visitor

---

(The following text is taken from [xnor's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/5791/2518) as he finished the solution. This answer is marked as accepted as the majority of the grunt-work was done by Warlord --Joe)

---

From there, I simply

> Googled the words.

This led me to

> The first paragraph of [The Hounds of Baskerville](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/2852/2852-h/2852-h.htm), a story featuring Sherlock Holmes, which contains these words.

As confirmation as to the answer

> the first chapter contains references to meeting at Waterloo Station.

I feel like I disregarded some information in my solution, so I'm curious if this is how it was intended to be solved.

Comment: Man, I've been looking for the right letters to swap the whole day. How did you find the right ones?

Comment: Yes, perfect first part. Don't forget the clues and you'll get further... +1 from me

Comment: @Aioros Looking at the words list I was all but positive the "B___KF____" had to be breakfast, so I just looked to try and make breakfast appear in the puzzle.

Comment: Great start! I've been trying to make sense of why those 12 letters are chosen to be swapped (`ACDEILNORSTY`), 12 are revealed (`BFGHKMPQUV`), and 4 are neither (`JWXZ`). They seem far from random: the revealed ones are common letters, but the traditional `ETAOIN SHRDLU` has a `U` rather than a `Y`. I thought of some proxies for commonness, but none of them fit either: Scrabble value, Morse code length, dots in Braille. The last two would also have a notion of complementation.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is

> The Hound of the Baskervilles

[Warlord 099's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/5772/4551) took me almost the whole way there. It suggests to:

> fill in partial words like `B***KF***` into words like `BREAKFAST`, then find them in the grid with a set of substitutions. For example, it becomes `BDSOKFOEC`, a string found backwards in the top row of the words search, with the substitutions `D<->R, S<->E, O<->A. C<->T`. Presumably, Warlord 099 found these by looking for snippets in the word search and finding consistent substitutions.

From there, I simply

> Googled the words.

This led me to

> The first paragraph of [The Hounds of Baskerville](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/2852/2852-h/2852-h.htm), a story featuring Sherlock Holmes, which contains these words.

As confirmation as to the answer

> the first chapter contains references to meeting at Waterloo Station.

I feel like I disregarded some information in my solution, so I'm curious if this is how it was intended to be solved.

Comment: I will add a small missing part here (it doesn't feel right to post a new answer since you two did the biggest part of the job): the letters to be swapped compose the words TRAINS and CDOYLE. Damn, I was so close yesterday, I wa trying something generic like trains and people. Well, great job anyway.

Comment: Oh, and just a small petty correction: the title is "The Hound of the Baskervilles". Otherwise it wouldn't really be a 5-words title :)

Comment: @Warlord099 Well done all of you, between the 3 of you (Warlord099, Xnor, Aioros) you've solved the complete puzzle. It is hard to attribute the sole victory in this case, but I'm tempted to accept Warlord's solution if he edits the title in with reference to Xnor. Would you agree? +1 on the comments and posts of all three of you. I'm also going to post "my" answer, because I want to explain the deductions route I _thought_ would lead to the solution.

Comment: @BmyGuest I think Warlord099 should get the accept for doing the brunt of the work -- I just Googled his results. Please do post your solution. I'm very curious how it goes.

Comment: You googled the words? Sadly, I never would have thought of that.... I was looking for a pattern out of the remaining letters in the puzzle...

Answer (score 6):

This is the solution as intended. The puzzle has been properly solved in a somewhat joint attempt between Warlord 099, Xnor and Aioros. I feel I should post this solution here for completeness sake:

---

## The hints:

The first two hints are auxiliary to narrow down the word search. They were edited in after I realized that the possibilities of the word-search might have been too many, if "anything allowed" has to be assumed.

```
Words are born as letters, but they reach adulthood when they are six. 
(And this puzzle is not child's play!)
```

> Simply a hint to disregard words with less than 6 letters in this puzzle. This is valid for both the word-search and then the book-search

```
You find us from East to West and West to East, from North to South and South to North. 
And in between, can we also be seen. 
We do not jump, we do not bend, a straight line we form, from start to end.
```

> Another clarification hint to narrow down the puzzle a bit. Indicates that the word-search is a standard 8-direction-straight-line-no-steps search in the grid.

The next hint is a critical one for the book-search. I think it is a real key-hint.

```
We meet at Waterloo station.
```

> Who is we? Well, *what* meets at a station? **Trains**. The word is needed further down. *Waterloo* is a smaller hint towards the geographic area but it is not really needed. *Central Station* would have been as good, but I wanted it a bit more themed.  (*Aioros figured that hint out. Well done.*)

### The word-search

This really was a crypto-word-search, so the additional clues needed where:

```
__ <-> __
__ <-> __
__ <-> __
__ <-> __
__ <-> __
__ <-> __
```

> 6 letter pairs are switched in this puzzle! Find those 6 pairs, and you've nearly solved it.

```
B*H***
B***KF***
H****H-*UG
**F**QU***
M*****G*
*********
P**K**
******
U*U****
V******
```

> Those where the 10 words actually hidden in the word-search. I thought it would be pretty obvious, but it turned out, that many thought in a different direction. The * indicate letters which where of the switched pairs while the "fixed" letters are given.

The idea was...

> ...that one could still find the *pattern* in the word-search, which would then give 10 words with mangled letters (sometimes more than one alternative, but never too many), and one could then solve this like a simple replacement cypher. i.e. the last word could only fit in two places of the puzzle and could only have been one of the following according to the word search: V*YEYCAD* or V*DCESLS*.

The way to find them...

> It is potentially easiest to first highlight the letters which are not changed, i.e. BHKFUGQMPV.

This gives:

> [image]

Next:

> If you match the pattern, of the given words, there are really only very few places they would fit. Some letters appear very rarely, and the space is limited.
>  For example, there is only one place where the pattern B*H of the first word fits.

Example:

> [image]

If you follow this through, you'll find all words:

> You now have to solve the replacement-cypher with a bit of 'feeling' for English words. This gives you all 6 letter-pairs as discovered by *Warlord 099*. (*Although he seems to have started out with the word breakfast regardless of the word-search!*).

If you'd sort in alphabetic increasing order, this would give:

> [image]

But now you need the word found from the important clue, giving you:

> [image]

Which brings you to the final part of the puzzle:

> C.Doyle is a rather known author and 'father' of Sherlock Holmes. The words found in the word-search appear an odd choice? Well, those are the first 10 words (of more than 5 letters) of one of the Sherlock books.

i.e.

> Mr. Sherlock Holmes, who was **usually** very late in the **mornings**, save
>  upon those not **infrequent** **occasions** when he was up all night, was
>  **seated** at the **breakfast** table. I stood upon the **hearth-rug** and **picked**
>  up the stick which our **visitor** had left **behind** him the night before.

### The solution

> The title of that book: **[The Hound of the Baskervilles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hound_of_the_Baskervilles)**

---

### CONCLUSIONS

**In the spirit of this site, I would like to invite others to comment (in this answer) how they like the puzzle; how deductive they think it is; if they could solve it, and if so because of what clues; what could be improved etc. etc.**

Comment: First of all, this was a fun and well thought puzzle, which is actually still rare on this site. I think I might have gone with the "pattern recognition" if only I hadn't failed to notice the Q and the U that were diagonally close. For some reason I couldn't for the life of me see them, so I thought there was some kind of scrambling around, too. I think the hard thing about this puzzle (for me) was the fact that it is - as you said - a whole, and not really a sequence of separate parts. But it was definitely doable, and well constructed.

Comment: Wow, great puzzle! And great teamwork from the solvers too. I think this is one of the best puzzles on the site, personally. It's original, it's solvable - fab.

Comment: Actually the word starting with a 'V' could have been anywhere in the puzzle since 'V' potentially could have switched with any other letter...

Comment: Oh I see... You would have to make the assumption that the letters given as clues are not subject to be changed. I did not make that assumption.

Comment: @Warlord099 Yes, you're right. That's an implicit assumption I though reasonable but did not explicitly state. Do you think such a statement would be needed? My argument was, that if "given" letters would be open to change, the puzzle would become arbitrary, so the implicit assumption should be enough.

Comment: Well... I was able to solve it even without that assumption, so I would say it was fine. But that is why I started with the word "breakfast" lol

Comment: That assumption was not obvious, but could be noticed: once you recognize "breakfast", "hearth-rug", "infrequent", you may realize that the hidden letters are the same in all words. I think it was a fair step.

Comment: @Aioros I agree. It makes it easier with it. It wasn't impossible without it. And it really wasn't unreasonable to come to that conclusion. I was just stating that I personally did not realize that until now.

Comment: I think this was a solid puzzle overall, but vulnerable to shortcutting. The multiple clues are well-themed and tight, but make it possible to get the answer with only some of them. If fact, someone looking only at the words with asterisks and nothing else could solve the puzzle by plugging them into [a regex with dictionary](http://www.onelook.com/), taking unique or most plausible answers, and [Googling the three most definite ones](https://www.google.com/search?q=breakfast%20hearth-rug%20infrequent) to find the answer. Actually, "hearth-rug" + "Waterloo Station" suffices.

Comment: For red herrings, I spent a while on on a formula for switching letters, mislead by their commonness, like switching dots and dashes in Morse code. I didn't consider making them words, nor the clue for "trains". I looked a lot at the leftover letters of the word search, as I thought switching them the same way would reveal a message. I didn't understand that "reach adulthood when they are six" meant six letters; I thought it meant to Caesar shift by 6. "And this puzzle is not child's play!" made me think it was saying not to use the Playfair Cipher, but Vigenere, loosely clued by "Waterloo".

Comment: @xnor thanks for the feedback, yes the clues where rather indicative, but similar to my other keyword in word search puzzle, the second part of the puzzle was more a verification step for the solution. I wanted to test how word-searches would work as deterministic pattern-match puzzle when one *can not* rely on the brain auto-identifying words. With this respect. Warlord did the main part - albeit differently than I thought.

Comment: @BmyGuest OK, I see what you mean about the verification. The wordsearch/substitution is definitely cute. It's a nice work step in that it keeps you mentally engaged and takes time, so the puzzle is not just done after a key insight. I wish I'd tried it rather than spoiling myself. If you want a wordsearch that needs to be solved by loose pattern recognition rather than finding specific strings of letters, maybe consider something like look-a-like letters or strings of letters that are pronounced similarly?